# Decimal Length Issue in c#

Tags: c#, decimal, custom-data-type

I am getting a number like below from the database:

```
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.32
```

We are getting error in Dataadapter.fill(dataset) method.

But it is throwing the following exception.

> Overflow Exception

.

Please suggest me a data type/approach which can store the data of length 32 with 2 decimal places.

Comment: There is 3rd party lib BigDecimal : https://gist.github.com/nberardi/2667136

Comment: you can send this id as string from `sql query` and convert in `double` if required. if you want to just display anywhere, then even not required to convert also

Comment: What is the datatype in the database? And what is is number actually suppose to represent?

Comment: What could be the actual use for a value of 1.2 duodecillion's?

Answer (score 2):

You can store it in double

```
double d = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.32;
```

Comment: I can store it in double.
But while displaying it is not showing full string.

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem with Oracle's "NUMBER" datatype. It is closely related to Decimal, but it may have many more digits. I recommend to truncate the value

```
TRUNC(your_value, 10)
```

and use a double in C# instead of Decimal.

Comment: i getting error in Dataadapter.fill(dataset) method.